# Is there a way to have an unmanaged chrome profile alongside a managed chrome profile on mac os?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-workspace

I have a mac (m2 pro running the latest 13.5 os) from work. My work also uses google workspace accounts. When you log into a google workspace in chrome, becomes managed by the workspace account enforcing certain settings in the browser. My specific issue is that they have the setting "have chrome offer to save passwords" setting disabled. This isn't an issue for work as we use different software for managing passwords at work. However this setting also is enforced on my personal chrome profile making updating and managing passwords for personal accounts a pain. Is there a way to work around this, perhaps by running a separate instance of chrome? I've previously installed other version of chrome (e.g. beta) and it becomes managed as well.

Additional Details.

- The machine is managed but loosely. I can install what I want on it.
- I open to using any version of chrome and a portable version as long as it lets me log into my account and manage my passwords.

Comment: It's never wise to use a work computer for personal data. What happens if you leave, or they want it back? You won't have the authority to secure erase it.

Comment: The passwords are encrypted and I can remotely remove authentication of the account from the machine. Also I'm not paranoid that my employer is going to try to steal my personal accounts.

Comment: Your workplace can set the chrome policy to apply to individual users or the entire enrolled browser/device: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2657289. It sounds like they set this at the device level if it's affecting your other user account, so there's no real options on your end

Comment: I think you should add more details. Does your company also manage the operative system? What is your Mac operative system name and version?  Are you open to using Chrome as a portable app? What about using another Chrome distribution like Chrome Canary? or Another web browser also based in Chromium?

Comment: The machine is managed but loosely. (I can install anything I need). I'm running mac os 13.4. I could use chrome as a portable app (I didn't see a good mac option for that). Other chromium derivatives don't include the google password management that I'm looking for. In the past I've tried other chrome distributions but they end up being managed as well.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add all the relevant details directly into the question body.

Answer (score 0):

The more straightforward solution is that you use a different web browser instead of insisting on using Chrome on your work computer.

You might try to have multiple copies of Chrome on your work computer, but you should be sure to differentiate one from the other. The copy you want to keep unmanaged should never be used to sign in using your work account; otherwise, there is a risk that your work settings for Chrome will be applied.

Please make sure to download the second copy directly from Google servers. Don't use a file distributed by your company. Also, ensure to use an Internet connection not managed by your company or routed through your company's network.

There are other options, like

- Using a solution for installing Chrome as a portable app.
- Install a second operating system or virtual machine.
- Run Chrome from a remote machine.

Comment: I looked for portable versions of chrome but couldn't find anything for mac os. A virtual machine could be a good solution.